# What are the free 3d OOP game engines?

Tags: vb.net

Could you please list a few free 3d OOP game engines, along with the pros and cons?
Embeddable in VB.net would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy to use cross-platform 3D engines for C++ game development?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21/easy-to-use-cross-platform-3d-engines-for-c-game-development)

Answer (score 3):

Existing questions which should answer you:

- [Linux Game Engines](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3383/linux-game-engines)
- [C++ Game Library](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2815/c-game-library-closed)
- [Game Engine framework or library](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2005/game-engine-framework-or-library)
- [Easy to use cross-platform 3D engines for C++ game development?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21/easy-to-use-cross-platform-3d-engines-for-c-game-development)
- [Pro's and Con's of Various 3D Game Engines](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/351/pros-and-cons-of-various-3d-game-engines)

Also see the [3D Game and Graphics Engines Database](http://www.devmaster.net/engines/).

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, don't post the duplicate, vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: If you agree with me that the question is a duplicate, don't vote me up, vote to close or vote down!

Comment: Well it's sort of like a 95% duplicate. There's not an /exact/ match. And I posted only to point out all the possible duplicates in a nicer format than a long comment of URLs.

Answer (score 2):

OGRE3D, IrrLicht, Horde3d, Panda3d.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language that you want to use. I have always liked the format of Java so I used the [jMonkeyEngine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/) to do this